# How to solve menu compilation errors when installing BERNESE on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install the Bernese GNSS Software 5.2 on Ubuntu 18.04. I already have installed Perl 5 and qt4.

The `setup.sh` runs but the compilings are giving error.

I first selected the compiler G95 and it gave error menu and FORTRAN programs and then with GNU compiler and the FORTRAN programs compiled well but the menu still giving error.

Also once I close the `setup.sh` I can not run the `configure.pm` that starts the configuration menu (and running the `setup.sh` again overwrites everything).

I am having the following error:

```
g++: error: .obj/release/menutils.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:225: recipe for target 'menu_tmp' failed
make: [menu_tmp] Error 1 (ignored)

================================================================================
Compilation finished
********************************************************************************
ERROR: Compilation not successful!
********************************************************************************
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
make: [.obj/release/menutils.o] Error 1 (ignored)
g++: error: .obj/release/menutils.o: No such file or directory
make: [menu_tmp] Error 1 (ignored)


'menu_tmp' and 'menu_tmp' are identical (not copied) at /BERN52/GPS/EXE/cmenu.pl line 223.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `configure.pm` error not running seemed to be from exporting the script from windows to linux I solve it by installing http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/ and running `dos2unix configure.pm`. After it executed the configuration menu correctly.

-To solve the compiling form the menu:

Running directly just the `cmenu.pl` that is the script that is called when compiling the menu it gives the same error but with more detail from the makefile. **It is missing zlib on makefile.**

```
/usr/bin/ld: .obj/release/menutils.o: undefined reference to symbol 'compress'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:225: recipe for target 'menu_tmp' failed
make: [menu_tmp] Error 1 (ignored)

================================================================================
Compilation finished
********************************************************************************
ERROR: Compilation not successful!
********************************************************************************
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: [menu_tmp] Error 1 (ignored)


'menu_tmp' and 'menu_tmp' are identical (not copied) at ./cmenu.pl line 226.
```

I first tried to include the lib on the LIBS in the MakeFile but it continued failing on compilation because it was remaking the MakeFile every time i run the compilation and erasing my changes.

This is how I solved and compiled well:

First launched the `setup.sh` as usual install everything and gave the error when compiling the menu. Then, after running the `dos2unix configure.pm` so I can access the configuration menu:

1 - Install zlib

`sudo apt-get install libz-dev`

2 - At GPS/EXE/cmenu.pl comment line 116 (avoid remaking the MakeFile so our changes won't be erased when we try to compile)

`# system("$qmake -Wall menu.tmp");`

3 - At MENU/MakeFile line 19 add -lz

`LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS)  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQt3Support -lQtGui -lQtNetwork -lQtCore -lpthread -lz`

4 - At MENU/MakeFile comment lines 227 to 255, that are remaking the MakeFile every run also.

```
# Makefile: menu.tmp  /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64/qmake.conf /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/unix.conf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/linux.conf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/gcc-base-unix.conf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/g++-base.conf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/common/g++-unix.conf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/release.prf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/shared.prf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/unix/gdb_dwarf_index.prf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/qt.prf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/unix/thread.prf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/moc.prf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/resources.prf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/uic.prf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
#       /usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/include_source_dir.prf \
#       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt3Support.prl \
#       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.prl \
#       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.prl \
#       /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.prl
#   $(QMAKE) -Wall -o Makefile menu.tmp
```

5 - Compile the menu again from the `configure.pm` and compiled successfully.